# Spring Boot - Lock Entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, locking

I'm using spring boot, so even spring data.
I need to be able to lock multiple simultaneous transactions on the same entity.
I'll explain:
there are two methods, one of writing and one of reading on the same entity; I would like to be able to lock the transaction that enters the reading method, if at that precise moment there is another transaction that has called the writing method; the transaction that calls the read method should then wait for the transaction that calls the write method to finish, so as not to have inconsistency in the data.
It's possible to do it?

These are my methods:

```
// reading method
public String getStationId(...) {
    return stationRepository.find(...);
}

// writing method
public void updateStations(List idList, ...) {
    stationRepository.updateStations(idList, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @Transactiona and  Isolation level:

**Propagation**

Defines how transactions relate to each other. Common options

**Required:** Code will always run in a transaction. Create a new transaction or reuse one if available.
**Requires_new:** Code will always run in a new transaction. Suspend current transaction if one exist.

**Isolation**

Defines the data contract between transactions.

**Read Uncommitted:** Allows dirty reads
**Read Committed:** Does not allow dirty reads
**Repeatable Read:** If a row is read twice in the same transaciton, result will always be the same
**Serializable:** Performs all transactions in a sequence

Additional info: 
http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial